# how to recover from failed transaction due to crash [mysql]?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb

I am trying to start MySQL server, but it keeps throwing errors. Upon inspecting I found out that the server was stopped unexpectedly and there was a transaction in the process that didn't finish. I had to delete some log files because the server was out of space and I deleted a `mariadb-bin` file that I assume contained some information required to perform `tc-heuristic-recover=ROLLBACK` recovery. Now when I run `sudo mysqld --tc-heuristic-recover=ROLLBACK` it aborts with error with the below message.

```
[ERROR] mysqld: File '/var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin.000486' not found (Errcode: 2 "No such file or directory")
[ERROR] Failed to open log (file '/var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin.000486', errno 2)
[ERROR] Could not open log file
[ERROR] Can't init tc log
[ERROR] Aborting
```

Answer (score 1):

> how to recover from failed transaction due to crash

The correct answer is "Let the database recover *itself*".
**Instance Recovery** is part and parcel of *every* major DBMS, including mysql/mariadb.  It just happens *automatically*.  You don't have to do anything.

> I had to delete some log files because the server was out of space ...

Yep; it happens all too often.

> ... I deleted a mariadb-bin file ...

And that was probably the very *worst choice* you could have made.

[Text] log files that you or I might read?
Trash 'em with impunity.

[Binary] log files used internally by the database?
Let well alone.  Leave them to the database to manage for itself.

You removed the *very file* that the database needed to perform its Instance Recovery and sort itself out.
Anything that you do now (unless you took a a backup of that file before deleting it) will involve losing [some] data ...   and that could land you in hot water with Management.

Comment: Well, I agree with you for the most part. I managed to get the DB up and running. I simply had to remove all binary files instance from the `mariadb-bin.index` file. And boom, it was all working. Thankfully it happened because a transaction failed and it wasn't because of something critical. Thanks anyways.